# Can't disable python environment/virtual when launching powershell

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I've installed anaconda and probably not sure if I've messed up some settings.

Whenever I open powershell a python environment shows in the ps command line in my case it's (base).

I then run the Command

```
conda deactivate
```

and the environment tag in powershell goes away.

[image]

The problem is the when I open a new powershell window the python environment shows up again, the same thing happens when I reboot the computer. This is annoying.

[image]

How can I disable it by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the expected behavior. Conda defaults to auto-activating the **base** environment in shells that have been initialized (e.g., `conda init powershell`). There is a setting for disabling auto-activation, `auto_activate_base`, which can be set with

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```